# Google Tag Manager - Click Element - CSS Selector - Trying to use an "href" as the trigger

Tags: css-selectors, href, eventtrigger, google-tag-manager-server-side

[overview debug mode of available variables](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W6RzH.png)
[1st Phone Number // href="tel:2293042344"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BihdI.png)
[2nd Phone Number // href="tel:8885142344"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e8AJI.png)

I'm hoping someone can shed some light on a little situation I'm currently stuck on. On my client's site, I'm trying to setup a couple of Events to fire on two separate phone numbers that have all the same variables, minus a difference in the "href". Maybe I'm approaching this wrong, I just can't find any other value to use that will distinguish between the two clickable-phone numbers. If I use developer tools > inspect, and copy the css selector of the element, both bring back the same information. But I did notice the href is different between the two. What's the appropriate method in which I can use the two different href's to create the Firing Trigger for either event? The help is really appreciated!

I've used: Just Links > URL contains > href="""
Click Element > CSS Selector > pasted the copied CSS from developer tools
Click Classes > contains > img-responsive wp-image-4678" (both have the same variable)

Not avaialbe = Click ID, Click Target, Click Text, Click URL (same), Click Classes (same)

Comment: paste html from around your links.

Comment: You have to create a custom trigger. you can find all information about it here https://developers.google.com/tag-platform/tag-manager/server-side/intro?hl=de#click_trigger